# Correlation between regression coefficients

Tags: regression, econometrics

Consider an i.i.d sample and assume the linear conditional expectation model

y<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub>$\beta$ + $\epsilon$<sub>i</sub>

${\mathbb{E}}$[$\epsilon$<sub>i</sub> | x<sub>i</sub>] = 0

In general, if I estimate $\beta$ many times, will it be correlated or uncorrelated? What is a sufficient condition so that all these $\beta$ will be uncorrelated?

Is it correct to say that the $\beta$s will be correlated and that the sufficient condition would be if the errors are homoskedastic? I'm having trouble explaining why they would be correlated and would appreciate any form of hints. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried writing out a formula for $\rho(\hat \beta_1,\hat \beta_2)$, where the numbers indicate two non-overlapping samples, and seeing how far you get?

Comment: If you have something in common between models, for example, that the samples are taken in some sense from the same population, then the more samples there are for two completely non-overlapping samples of that larger population, the closer a $\beta_1$ will be to a $\beta_2$ in value. Thus, if you then have a set of $n$ $\beta$ values from the same population, but not the same samples, they will clustered and form a distribution. This is not a "correlation" so you may consider rethinkiing how you have posited tthe question.